# jQuery: Validation based on constant value, eg (+50 or -50) constant value with same currency

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have requirement like I need to compare one threshold value with sum of the total value (count) and will compare like based on threshold if threshold value `+50 or -50` and selected records have same currency. Need to do the successful validation. If beyond more than `+50 or -50` not allowed to success validation.

I tried the below validation, its passing at `+50` (passed) and failed at `-50` (failed) validation.

```
var theresholdVal = 50;
for (let i = 0; i < jsonData1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < jsonData2.length; j++) {
        if (jsonData1[i]['Currency'] !== jsonData2[j]['Currency']) {
            alert("Currency is mismatched, please select same currency!!!");
            return false;
        } else if (theresholdVal <= parseInt(countVal)) {
            alert("Selected value is more thereshold value");
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("Data matched successfully!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mhcxeg5/2/)

Comment: Hi, so you want total value in range ? i.e : `+50 -  -50` ?

Comment: Yes, need to compare countval(+50/ -50) with threshold value.

Comment: you can add one more condition `else if ((-1 * theresholdVal) >= parseInt(countVal)) {`

Comment: I tried the similar solution, (theresholdVal <= parseFloat(countVal) + parseFloat(theresholdVal))||
                          (theresholdVal <= parseFloat(countVal) - parseFloat(theresholdVal))

Comment: Yeah, it is working now..